# How to make Dreamweaver CS6 to highlight statements begin and end like NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, dreamweaver

In NetBeans, there is a nice feature that it can highlight(in yellow) the begin and end of a statement or a HTML tag. But in Dreamweaver CS6, I could not find such feature. Is it possible to do it in DW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option for that in Dreamweaver CS6, you'll have upgrade to CC for that option.

Comment: thanks, I will update to CC(just realized that CC is released after CS6)